# Create DB in SQL Server based on Visio Data Model

Tags: sql-server, database, visio, scripting

I have created a database model in Visio Professional (2003). I know that the Enterprise version has the ability to create a DB in SQL Server based on the data in Visio. I do not have the option to install Enterprise. Aside from going through the entire thing one table and relationship at a time and creating the whole database from scratch, by hand, can anyone recommend any tool/utility/method for converting the visio database model into a SQL Script that can be used to create a new DB in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

I have not done this, but here it goes.

1. Convert Visio file to Visio XML format.
2. Use [Dia for Windows](http://dia-installer.de/index_en.html) and [Dia VDX plug-in](http://www.redferni.uklinux.net/dia/vdx/) to convert Visio XML into Dia.
3. Use [tedia2sql](http://tedia2sql.tigris.org/) to generate SQL.

Comment: I tried to download this. It looks like the VDX plugin has been integrated with the main Dia program, as it did offer support to open VDX files. However, it does not support all parts of Visio files. With regards to tedia2sql, it seems like there is no binary download, and in order to get it to work, I would have to download additional modules and compile it myself. Since according to its website it hasn't even been thoroughly tested for MSSQL, I don't think it is worth spending the time trying to get this working. Thanks for the links though.

Answer (score 1):

For visio 2010 there is nice plugin Visio Forward Engineer:

http://forwardengineer.codeplex.com/

[image: Plugin adds one more tab to Visio]

Answer (score -2):

If you can somehow obtain the type library from the enterprise version you can use VBA to get out the definitions.  Secondhand enterprise architect versions of VS 2002 and VS 2003 can be brought from ebay for a few hundred dollars.