# SQL Server repagination when printing a diagram

Tags: sql-server

After laying out my schema diagram in SQL Server (both 2000 and 2005), I want to print a copy to paper. When I go to print, SQL seems intent on recalculating the pagination (and getting it very wrong).

I'm simply printing to the default printer - an HP Officejet. I've tried forcing a repagination before manually adjusting it. Saving and reopening the diagram before printing.

I've looked at other external solutions - screen capture, Visio, MS Access - but they all have other complications. I like the feature to layout diagrams in SQL Server and it suits me very well, except when I want a hard copy printout.

What's the deal with this very unhelpful "feature" of SQL Server?

Comment: I ended up writing a routine to read the table structure and generate a jpg image which could be dumped onto a Publisher page. I don't get the relationship links, but at least I can lay out a schema with the table structures and have them print the way I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to print the SQL Diagrams has always been an issue.  That's about the best answer I can give you.

Answer (score 0):

I must confess I use PrintScreen and Paint when printing a SQL server schema diagram. This so far has been the only thing that works for me. Recently I have been using [Dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/) to create Entity-Relation diagrams. As mentioned here in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672/create-db-in-sql-server-based-on-visio-data-model), you could use Dia to create a SQL script based on the diagram.