# Forward engineer from Visio to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, visio, erd

I have created an ERD in Visio 2007. Now I want to take my ErD design and export it to SQL Server 2008 and create a new database based on my diagram.

I can locate much information on reverse engineering but little on forward.

How can I get this ERD out of Visio ?

Comment: MS stopped implementing the forward engineering for some time. Defintely it isn't available in Visio 2010 and it might not be available also in 2007. There is an add-on on the web, don't know how good it is http://forwardengineer.codeplex.com/

Comment: @mslliviu yes after much searching finally found http://forwardengineer.codeplex.com/ as well. I will have to try it out as Visio is basically useless without this feature.

Comment: Additionally if anyone wants this feature I found a request page on microsoft where it can be upvoted https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/617541/forward-engineering-create-tables-for-visio-professional-2010#

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672/create-db-in-sql-server-based-on-visio-data-model/17306486#17306486

Comment: I always found it much faster to rough out the design on paper, write the scripts to create the tables and then create pretty diagrams later.